# Sitecore Aggregation in Preview Mode

Tags: aggregation

I want to ask, is sitecore aggregation feature working for preview mode page? Because if i tried, the aggregation doesn't work if in preview mode. Or is there any configuration to enable it? Btw i'm using Sitecore 8.2 Thank you.